# MS SQLXML. Import XML with specified namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, sqlxml, bulk-load

I have to import XML data into a SQL Server database. I have the following XML (for example):

```
<ROOT xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
  <Customer CustomerID="1" CompanyName="xyz" />
  <Customer CustomerID="2" CompanyName="abc" />
</ROOT>
```

With the schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
  <xsd:element name="Customer" sql:relation="Customers" >
   <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:attribute name="CustomerID" type="xsd:string" />
     <xsd:attribute name="CompanyName" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

And running standard MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms172633.aspx) VBScript `SQLXMLBulkLoad` will succeed, however no data will be loaded.

If you delete the namespace reference (xmlns attribute), it will work.

XSD doesn't allow you to map attribute 'xmlns', so `sql:mapped='false'` does not work here.

Problem is, source XML cannot be changed, is it even possible to solve the issue using only XSD schema?

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple with standard XQuery that's available in SQL Server **2005** or newer:

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML = '<ROOT xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
  <Customer CustomerID="1" CompanyName="xyz" />
  <Customer CustomerID="2" CompanyName="abc" />
</ROOT>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
SELECT
    ID = XC.value('@CustomerID', 'int'),
    CompanyName = XC.value('@CompanyName', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @XmlData.nodes('/ROOT/Customer') XT(XC)
```

Gives me an output of:

[image]

which could very easily be used in a `INSERT INTO ....` statement, too

Comment: Thanks! That is actually a good way to manage the issue. However, I'm still curious if it can be done with SQLXMLBulkLoad and proper XSD schema.